# Angular 8 HttpClient: Unable to process text/csv server response

Tags: angular, http-headers, httpclient

I have a endpoint which returns a csv data set which will be saved using `saveas` and `Blob`
AngularJS frontend works fine while Angular 8 struggles.
Here is my Angular 8 implementation

```
 const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            Accept: 'text/csv',
        });
        const options = { headers };
        this.httpClient
            .post<ExportCsvSettingsViewDto>(this.appConfigService.buildApiUrl(this.loadPath(batchId)), csvDto, options)
            .subscribe((fileResult: any) => {
                const file = new Blob([fileResult], { type: 'text/csv' });
                saveAs(file, this.fileName + '.csv');
            });
```

This results in a `HttpErrorResponse` stating:
*Object {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at positio…, text: "1.112.373;en-US
Date Time UTC;Date Local Time;Bat…"}*

I suspect this is because `HttpClient` treats the response as `JSON` instead of `"text/csv"`
Those were the request headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 141
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/csv
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

and response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/csv
Expires: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Length: 191147
```

I tried to explicitly set `"responseType"` in request header to `"text/csv"` but that's just not possible.
Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 7):

In case anybody cares:
My suspicion was right: the response was considered to be of type `json`.
Setting `responseType='text'` worked by doing like this:

```
  const options = { headers, responseType: 'text' as any };
```

I consider this to be a big issue actually